# Unable to work effectively with Git locally

Tags: git

*Please, see [Greg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053867/unable-to-work-effectively-with-git-locally/1053879#1053879).*

I do not understand Daniel's statement at [the thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048827/unable-to-copy-all-but-files-and-gitconfig-to-git-repo/1048878#1048878) completely:

> Why are you manually copying files
>   around at all? Surely you should just
>   add them to the repo, then check out
>   and commit as necessary. I don't see
>   the need to move the files around -
>   that seems to defeat the whole purpose
>   of a local checkout.

I am at the moment using rsync in coping files from

1. ~/bin/
2. ~/        (only some dot-files)

Daniel's statement suggests me that there may be a better way to do the workflow locally.

I am not sure what he means by

> Surely you should just add them to the repo, then check out and commit as necessary.

It seems that he is not speaking about git-add.

**How can you add files to your repo,** not with git-add?

Comment: you should maybe edit your first question or add a comment to Daniel's answer instead of asking a new question

Comment: @tanascius: I disagree with you. I have noticed questions gets too challenging to follow if I ask them at comments, since I cannot use any emphasizing features in comments.

Comment: maybe you should at least add a comment to Daniel's answer. At least it is his answer you do not understand - and maybe he doesn't even know about this new question.

Comment: @taniscius: You are right. I will do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what Daniel was referring to is using Git to manage the files in particular directories in place, without copying them around. For example, starting without any Git repository, you might:

```
cd ~/bin
git init
git add .
```

Now, your `~/bin` directory contains a `~/bin/.git` repository and you can `git add` and `git diff` right from the `~/bin` directory.

Comment: @Greg: He seems to mean: to keep many gits and then adding branches from various places to your github-dev-branch such that you combine the final product from these different branches.

Answer (score 1):

1) I back up my .dotfiles as follows:

a) Create a directory ~/dotfiles

b) link dotfile into ~/dotfiles/ e.g.

```
ln ~/.bashrc ~/dotfiles/.bashrc  # NB Must be hard links
```

c)

```
cd ~/dotfiles
git init
git add .  
git commit -m "Initial commit of dotfiles"
```

2) You can also refer to a Git repo not in the current directory tree by exporting the environment string GIT_DIR .e.g (assuming at repo at ~/myrepos/repo1)

a)

```
 export GIT_DIR=~/myrepos/repo1/.git
```

b)

```
 git add .profile  
 git commit -m "added .profile"
```

Does that help at all?

Comment: @Alec: I remember that Git does not follow either softlinks or hardlinks. Your answer suggests me that Git does follow hardlinks.

Comment: @Alec: Assume you export GIT_DIR. How can you reper to your Git repo then?

Comment: @Masi You don't 'follow' hard links. A hard link is an additional directory entry that references the same file and has equal 'status' as the original name. Every tool that looks on the file system just sees a file. So Git sees files as well.

Comment: @Masi because you export GIT_DIR then Git will reference the correct repo -- the Git tools are responsible for reading GIT_DIR.

Comment: @Alec: You have only one .gitconfig -file which affects all git -repositories in your computer. If you add the git_dir to .gitconfig, it apparently makes a link from the main Git at Root to the git at the wanted location (I am guessing here).

Comment: I added the Git_dir -command, to a Git at /tmp/ which refers to a Git at ~/bin (export GIT_DIR=~/bin/.git. --- I can see no change in my .gitconfig nor in any files at /tmp/. --- What is the purpose of the command?

Comment: @Masi It's not a command and does not add anything to .gitconfig.  It's an environment string  just tells Git where the current repo is.